# Can't connect to PostgreSQL database after pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I fear this may be a dumb question/easy fix, but have been stuck for a while. Would really appreciate any feedback you may have.

Both my development and production databases are Postgres. After pushing to Heroku, I was having issues with my scss files in my development environment. (Updates to the SCSS files were not reflected in my DEVELOPMENT environment, despite having the default config. settings. Not sure if this is an expected result from precompiling for the production env.)

After restarting my system, I can no longer connect to the Postgres database. I get the same error through the command line (rails s) and pgAdminIII, that says, "

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the
server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 
5432?
```

My files are configured as below, and fit the descriptions given in the other posts I found related to this issue. Also, I am able to access localhost:3000 with my SQLite3 projects.
Any feedback would be appreciated.

My postgresql.conf file

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# - Connection Settings -
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
max_connections = 100
```

My pg_hba.conf file

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the postgres process is running?

Comment: Hi @elithrar, could you tell me how I can confirm whether the postgres process is running? I've launched PGAdminIII the same way I have in the past, but haven't run any specific commands outside of rails server.

Comment: `pg_ctl status` to see if it's up, and `pg_ctl start` to start it. You may need to do a `pg_ctl reload` if you changed the configuration files and its still running (likely!) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/app-pg-ctl.html

Comment: Thanks @elithrar, I think I need to reinstall postgres, as I can't access pg commands through the command line from my project directory. (I need to go to the pg directory at postgresql/8.4/bin in order to execute the commands, despite having these paths in my system path.). Hopefully a reinstall will heal both problems...

Comment: I don't think you'll need to - chances are you just haven't set your path up right. What does `echo $PATH` at the command line give you? What OS are you running?

Comment: @elithrar. I'm on Windows. I reinstalled before your message, and echo $PATH shows C:/PostgreSQL/9.0/bin and C:/PostgreSQL/9.0/lib which should be correct. (I entered them in the system and user paths). I can start the server only by entering, "c:\postgresql\9.0\bin\postgres -D c:/user/umezo/pgdata." Once I disconnect (right-click on "PostgreSQL 9.0 (x86)(localhost:5432)" in pgAdminIII), I can only reconnect by re-entering the long command, which returns: "database not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress," before "autovacuum launcher started." Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a full [uninstall](http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/1437.page), then configured the postgres service to [use my local system account](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314357/EN-US). Now I can connect to my postgres server without issue.